# Get all field values from subclasses in Scala

Tags: scala

I have three class's

```
class A (
  param1:Int,
  param2:Int
)

class B (
  param3:Int,
  param4:Int
)

class C(
 param1:A,
 param2:B
)
```

And i need map between name of field to object, like

```
param1->1
param2->2
param3->3
param4->4
```

So i tired to did it as below but field its not type of Product

```
  def func1(c: C): Map[String, Object] = {
    var map = Map[String, Object]()
    for (field <- c.getClass.getDeclaredFields) yield {
      map ++ getFieldMap(field))
    }
  }

  def getFieldMap(p: Product): Map[String, Object] = {
    var values = p.productIterator
    p.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getName -> {
      values.next.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] 
    }).toMap
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala reflection to access all public fields at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465661/scala-reflection-to-access-all-public-fields-at-runtime)

Comment: The dupe, notification is only part of the solution. Sorry, you will need to get all subclasses beforehand. However, then it will be probably the same solution as in the provided link above. Assuming that you really want the sublcass' fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple problems with your code. The `class A` and `class B` do not implement the `Product` trait. You either have to do `with Product` manually and implement all the methods, or you declare them as `case` classes.

```
case class A (
  val param1: Int,
  val param2: Int
)

case class B (
  val param3: Int,
  val param4: Int
)
```

To ensure that Scala actually generates fields for the constructor parameters, add the `val` keyword in front.

Furthermore, you are passing the *field* (`java.lang.reflect.Field`), not it's value, which you have to get first.

```
def func1(c: C): Map[String, Object] = {
  var map = Map[String, Object]()
  for (field <- c.getClass.getDeclaredFields) yield {
    field.setAccessible(true) // <- to avoid IllegalAccessException
    map ++ getFieldMap(field.get(c)) // <- inserted .get(c)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried `a.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.get(a))` and got an IllegalAccessException

Comment: @GiovaniCaporaletti I assume Clashsoft is correct that you mean these as case classes? Without, I don't even get any fields - the param1 and param2 just become nameless constructor arguments

Comment: @NathanKronenfeld see my edit. You need to use `field.setAccessible(true)` before accessing it, like in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make your classes case classes, you can do it using shapeless:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.record._
case class A (param1:Int, param2:Int)

val a = A(12, 34)

val AGen = LabelledGeneric[A]
val map = AGen.to(a).toMap.map { case (k, v) => (k.name, v) }

println(map("param1")) // prints "12"
```